# Django object's id isn't available after save

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following `Bank` model:

```
from django.db import models

class Bank(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    identifier = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'bank'
        app_name = 'mcif'
```

Now look at this:

```
>>> from mcif.models import *
>>> b = Bank()
>>> b.name = "wee"
>>> b.identifier = "wee"
>>> b.save()
>>> b.id
>>>
```

If I understand how Django works, that `Bank` object is supposed to get updated with the id of the saved record. Any idea why this isn't happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a problem in Django when dealing with BigInt as Autoincrementing PK. Maybe this code snippet helps you solve this issue. Its a makeshift [solution](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1244/)

Comment: Dumb question: where do I put that file? And after I put it there, is there anything else I need to do?